# Netty Latency issue

Tags: performance, netty

I am a new user netty. I am using netty 4.0.19-Final version. I am load testing the EchoServer example with 50 clients. Below is my configuration. I am always getting latency of around 300 mcroseconds. I am trying to reduce the latency to around 100 microseconds. Is there anything i can try to achieve desired performance? All my clients are persistent clients and will send messages with a delay of 10 milliseconds.

```
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .localAddress(NetUtil.LOCALHOST, Integer.valueOf(8080))
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)


                .childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, 1045678)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1045678)
                .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                 // .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
                            throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline()
                        //.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                                .addLast(new EchoServerHandler());
                    }
                });

        // Start the server.
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(PORT).sync();

        // Wait until the server socket is closed.
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();

           EchoServerHandler:
  @Override
  public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
      ctx.write(msg);

  }

  @Override
  public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
      ctx.flush();
  }

  @Override
  public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
      // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
      cause.printStackTrace();
      ctx.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call ctx.writeAndFlush(...) Also you may need to adjust buffer sized etc.